# Allowing table columns to be ordered by DESC/ASC?

Tags: jquery, twig

I'm trying to figure out a way to allow employees to be able to sort the table. I was thinking I would create a select box with options and once an option is clicked (i.e. Filename) then the table would order by Filename descending. I'm using Twig as my templating language but can't find a way to do it with it. What's the best way I could go about doing this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.remove').on('click', function(event){

        $.post('phplib/remove_forward.php', {
                'id' : $(this).data('id')
            },function(data){
                if(data === 'true'){
                    $(event.target).parent().parent().remove();
                }
                console.log(data);
            },'html');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
<div id='content'>
    <h1>Signoffs</h1>
    <p>Sort by:<select id='sortby'><option></option><option>Filename</option></select></p>
    <table class='fancy'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Filename</th>
                <th>Another name</th>
                <th>Machine</th>
                <th>Operator</th>
                <th>Leader</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for item in signoffs %}
            <tr>
                <th><a href='http://files.example.com/folder/{{ item.job_folder }}/department/Files/{{ item.dep.file_name }}'>{{ item.dep.file_name }}</a></th>
                <td><a href='view.php?num={{ item.num }}&amp;file_id={{ item.dep.id }}'>Lineup</a></td>
                <td>{{ item.machine.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.operator.user.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.leader.user.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.date|date('M d, Y') }}</td>
                <td><a class='remove' data-id='{{ item.id }}' href=''>remove</a></td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [dataTables](http://www.datatables.net) its a wonderful jquery plugin that allows table manipulation.

Its extremely simply to use and very recommended.